# How to get value of {@docroot} in a com.sun.javadoc.Taglet?

Tags: java, javadoc, taglet

I'm writing a custom taglet for inclusion of a mathML file in a javadoc html file. I would like to store all my *.mml files in the same folder, possibly in the

```
{@docroot}/doc-files
```

folder. My question is : how can I know the value of the @docRoot string within a Taglet object (more specifically, within the `toString(com.sun.javadoc.Tag tag)` method ?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I also needed to display MathML in my javadoc. I wrote a blog post about how I solved it here: http://chadretz.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/mathml-inside-javadoc-using-mathjax-and-a-custom-taglet/

More specifically to your problem though, if you look at the Taglet source code I posted there (collapsed by default), you can see where I get the top level ClassDoc of the Tag.holder() to obtain the directory depth I am at so I can traverse up. This helps if you need the relative HTML root. If you need to know the location of your MML's while the Taglet is running, I suggest you put them on the classpath and access them as resources.

Answer (score 0):

Starting with the `getPackageDoc` function from [@ChadRetz's blog](http://chadretz.wordpress.com/2010/12/19/mathml-inside-javadoc-using-mathjax-and-a-custom-taglet/), I've created a utility class that contains a function that does what you wish: Given a `com.sun.javadoc.Tag`, it returns the relative url from its enclosing file (the file containing that tag), to the JavaDoc root directory--this is the equivalent of `{@docRoot}`.

The class is called [`ComSunJavaDocUtil`](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/com/github/aliteralmind/codelet/taglet/ComSunJavaDocUtil.html), and the function name is [`getRelativeUrlToDocRoot`](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/com/github/aliteralmind/codelet/taglet/ComSunJavaDocUtil.html#getRelativeUrlToDocRoot%28com.sun.javadoc.Tag%29).

An example taglet's `toString()` function:

```
public String toString(Tag tag) {
   return  "Relative url to DOC ROOT for this tag's enclosing file is \"" + 
      ComSunJavaDocUtil.getRelativeUrlToDocRoot(tag) + "\"";
}
```

This utility class is part of [Codelet](http://codelet.aliteralmind.com). Installation instructions are [here](http://aliteralmind.com/docs/computer/programming/codelet/documentation/javadoc/overview-summary.html#install). If this utility class is all you're going to use, then the only jars you need on your classpath are `codelet` and `xbnjava`...and, of course, `com.sun.javadoc`.